# Weird NullPointerException in StringTemplate map operation

Tags: java, stringtemplate, stringtemplate-4

This is my StringTemplate template for generating `import` statements, which does map operation on the anonymous template `{i | import <i>;<\n>}` for every value in `imports` .

`importdecl(imports) ::= "<if(imports)> <imports: {i | import <i>;<\n>}> <endif>"`

This throws `java.lang.NullPointerException at org.stringtemplate.v4.misc.ErrorManager.runTimeError(ErrorManager.java:133)`.

And the weird part is, when I change `i` to something else, this works perfectly and I'm sure that there is no difference in the input in both the cases. Like this doesn't throw error,

`importdecl(imports) ::= "<if(imports)> <imports: {r | import <r>;<\n>}> <endif>"`

Is `i` reserved or something in StringTemplate or am I missing something?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`<i>` is used to access the 1 based index in the array.

For example,

```java
ST st = stGroup.getInstanceOf("importdecl");
int[] data = {4, 5};
st.add("imports", data);
System.out.println(st.render());
```

with a template of

```
importdecl(imports) ::= <<
  <if(imports)><imports: {k | import <i><k>;<\n>}><endif>
>>
```

Prints:

```
import 14;
import 25;
```

I'd suggest using a different variable name :)

[More info here](https://github.com/antlr/stringtemplate4/blob/master/doc/cheatsheet.md) and [here](https://github.com/antlr/stringtemplate4/blob/master/doc/templates.md#discussion-3)

Comment: Yes I totally overlooked by taking it for granted!

Answer (score 1):

## Yes i is reserved.List of reserved keywords:

i, i0

## The iteration number indexed from one and from zero, respectively, when referenced within a template being applied to an attribute or attributes.

- default
- first
- group
- if
- implements
- interface
- last
- length
- optional
- rest
- strip
- super
- trunc
- else
- endif
- elseif

Comment: Can you provide a link to the source you found the keywords?

Comment: You state that `i` is reserved, but it is not in your list of reserved keywords. Can you clarify?

Comment: @StephanHogenboom See [Reserved words](https://theantlrguy.atlassian.net/wiki/spaces/ST/pages/1409038/StringTemplate+cheat+sheet).

Comment: @StephanHogenboom https://theantlrguy.atlassian.net/wiki/spaces/ST/pages/1409038/StringTemplate+cheat+sheet